# Cyrus-Imap - STARTTLS negotiation failed

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I'm configuring a mail server on Fedora and i have a problem.

I can autenthicate using Horde, but, when i try to authenticate using THunderbird, i get this message: `configuration could not be verified - is the username or password wrong`

In `/var/log/maillog` i get:

Dec 28 15:44:58 example cyrus/imap[17892]: STARTTLS negotiation failed: [192.168.1.158]

My `/etc/imapd.conf`

```
configdirectory: /var/lib/imap
partition-default: /var/spool/imap
partition-news: /var/spool/news
newsspool: /var/spool/news
altnamespace: no
unixhierarchysep: no
lmtp_downcase_rcpt: yes
admins: cyrus
allowanonymouslogin: no
popminpoll: 1
autocreatequota: 10000
umask: 077
sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail
sieveusehomedir: false
sievedir: /var/spool/sieve
hashimapspool: true
allowplaintext: yes
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
sasl_pwcheck_method: auxprop
sasl_auxprop_plugin: sasldb
sasl_auto_transition: no
tls_cert_file: /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_key_file: /etc/pki/cyrus-imapd/cyrus-imapd.pem
tls_ca_file: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
tls_ca_path: /var/imap
tls_session_timeout: 1440
tls_cipher_list: TLSv1+HIGH:!aNULL:@STRENGTH
update_retry_delay

idlemethod: poll
idlesocket: /var/run/cyrus/socket/idle
notifysocket: /var/run/cyrus/socket/notify
syslog_prefix: cyrus
```

How can i correct this?

Comment: Does your server support STARTTLS auth method for imap server ? You can try plain auth or SSL auth in thunderbird to see if auth goes right. Btw are you using username@DOMAIN in thunderbird for auth ? Your cyrus could be configured as multidomain and need the @DOMAIN part in the username to correctly query the user db to authenticate.

Comment: Just posted my imapd.conf file @maudam
In thunderbird i can login if i don't use any authentication

Comment: Maybe you mean using plain auth. Without auth you cannot access the account. Looking at your config, try to use ssl instead of starttls.